# Axis Orientation in 3D plot

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, matlab-figure, axis

I am having trouble creating a 3D plot, with the x-axis horizontal, the z-axis vertical, and the y-axis angled into the page.  For example:

[image: Example]

I tried to use the `view` function and camera orientations, but I don't think that's helping. Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: Please show us some code and what you've tried so far. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Any 3D plot in Matlab keeps the z-axis vertical, but cannot have a 3D view with the X-axis horizontal.  No combination of the view function will accomplish this.  I am not sure how to continue have a 3D view of the surface and while keeping the x-axis horizontal and y-axis vertical.  

[X,Y,Z] = peaks(30);
surf(X,Y,Z)
view([a b])

Comment: swap X and Z when plotting the data?